# How to stop a UdpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm listening to a UDP socket by using an `UdpClient`:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new(new IPEndPoint(myLocalAddress, 12345));
udpClient.Receive();
```

Indeed, this blocks. Because of this, I moved this code in a separate `Task`.

On a change of the network, I will stop no longer needed `UdpClient`s. For this, I use the `NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged` event.

How can I stop the listening of the `UdpClient`s? The `UdpClient.Receive` method does not allow a `CancellationToken`.

I also tried to use a `Socket` directly by using `Socket.Receive(datagram)`. But I can't stop this too.

Both ways do not stop, even the IP address is no longer present, because the network gone.

Comment: There's a `ReceiveAsync` method that accepts a cancellation token. If you're already in the context of a task, why not use that?

Comment: @JonSkeet IIRC a cancellation token cannot cancel `ReceiveAsync` after it starts, I've seen some discussions on github: [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23736) [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16236) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17711), you need another thread to call `Dispose` on the client.

Comment: @shingo: Those discussions were a few years ago - I wonder if things have improved. But yes, disposing of the UdpClient is definitely an alternative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `async` version of receive (`UdpClient.ReceiveAsync`). This should accept a Cancellation token in .net 6 (but not in .net-core 3.1 and earlier)